# jQuery selector not work in ie8: dymanic element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8

I have a problem with IE8 and selector of dymanic element.
In my script I append some element to a div with

```
$(".thumbnail ." + tmp + " #thumb_container:last-child").append(
  ' <img class="video-canvas-thumb" />' +
  ' <div class="border-thumb"></div>');
```

The code works well.
In another part of the code, I get some element with `var mini = $('.video-canvas-thumb');`. It works well with Chrome but IE8 not find elements.
I try also

```
var mini = $(".thumbnail div").find(".video-canvas-thumb");
var mini = $(".thumbnail").children("div").children("div").children("img.video-canvas-thumb");
```

but nothing change. I tested `find()` also.

Here there is my code:

```
setTimeout(function(){  
    $("#flash").fadeOut("slow", function(){
        var mini_thumb = document.querySelector('.video-canvas');   
        var mini = $(".thumbnail").children("div").children("div").children("img.video-canvas-thumb‌​"); 
        $(mini).each(function(index, element) { 
            setTimeout(function(){  
                $(element).attr("src", mini_thumb.toDataURL("image/png"));  
            }, 150);    
        }); 
    });
}, 800);
```

`$(mini)` is empty.

Is there a method to solve it? Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? jQuery 2.x doesn't support IE8.

Comment: I use jQuery v1.11.1 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc.

Comment: would you post your markup to have a look at?

Comment: Here there is my code: 
`setTimeout(function(){    
  $("#flash").fadeOut("slow", function(){      
   var mini_thumb = document.querySelector('.video-canvas');       
   var mini = $(".thumbnail").children("div").children("div").children("img.video-canvas-thumb");
              
   $(mini).each(function(index, element) {                
    setTimeout(function(){     
        $(element).attr("src", mini_thumb.toDataURL("image/png"));       
    }, 150); 
   });  
  })
 }, 800);`

$(mini) is empty

Comment: Do you have suggestion?

Comment: Maybe the problem would be that I have 12 divs, all with the same id #thumb_container ??

Comment: `for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
var tmp = a;
$(".thumbnail ." + tmp).append('<div id="thumb_container" >');
if (j == 0) {
  $(".thumbnail ." + tmp + " #thumb_container:last-child").append('<img src=' + a + "_card" + j + ".png" + ' width="100%" border="0" class="active" />')
 } else {
$(".thumbnail ." + tmp + " #thumb_container:last-child").append('<img src=' + a +"_card" + j + ".png" + ' width="100%" border="0" />')
}
$(".thumbnail ." + tmp + " #thumb_container:last-child").append(
'<img class="video-canvas-thumb"  />' +
'<div class="border-thumb"></div></div>');
 }`

Comment: The problem is that IE doesn't create the image.
The last code, don't work. Why??

`$(".thumbnail ." + tmp + " #thumb_container:last-child").append(
                ' <img class="video-canvas-thumb" src="image/cuore.png" />' +
                ' <div class="border-thumb"></div> ' +
                '</div>');`

Comment: Try deleting the leading spaces before `<img ...>` and `<div ...>`.